# Difference between tar and cp

Tags: tar, cp

I have a microSD card to which I am writing a linux kernel and root filesystem.

If I create the root filesystem using tar then my board has no problem booting from the microSD card.

If I create the root filesystem using cp then the system hangs halfway during boot.  The kernel boots OK but the system hangs when trying to start openssh.

TAR command:

```
sudo tar xfp ./debian-7.1-minimal-armhf-2013-08-25/arm*-rootfs-*.tar -C /media/rootfs/
sync
```

CP command:

```
sudo tar xfp ./debian-7.1-minimal-armhf-2013-08-25/arm*-rootfs-*.tar -C ./fileSystem/debian/
sudo cp  -p -r ./fileSystem/debian/* /media/rootfs
sync
```

Comment: What system is the SD card for?  e.g. Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I'm using a beaglebone black

Comment: For my raspberry pi I needed to use dd (or was it DD) to put the bootable OS image on the SD card, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think cp is coping your symbolic links properly.  Add -P (upper case) option to your cp command.  That will ensure your symbolic links get copied properly.  If on a mac use -a instead of -P.